# Asciidoc. How to display complex regex correctly in a table cell

Tags: regex, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I need to display some complex regular expression "as-is", i.e. w/o any modifications. Of course i can modify this regex to make asciidoc engine render it as needed for me, but are there more convenient ways to do that? Are there any ways to tell asciidoc to just display some string? W/o any modifications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick look at the docs suggests it's the same as in Markdown: either surround the regex with backticks, or place it in its own indented paragraph.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Alan. It seems i didn't make a right question. I need to place regex in a table cell. My regex contains the '|' symbol which is also a cell delimiter in asciidoc tables. So neither backticks nor separate paragraph didn't help(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the parser, Asciidoctor first finds cell delimiters and only then looks inside the cells. This means that even marking your cell as literal will not allow you to avoid escaping the `|`. The only alternative processing is for CSV table content, but then you will have to escape any `,` appearing in the regex.

My 2 most successful attempts were:

- using a literal block (note the escaped `\|`):

  ```
  [cols="1a,1"]
  |===
  |....
  a\|b
  ....
  |done
  |===
  ```

  or

  ```
  [cols="1l,1"]
  |===
  |a\|b
  |done
  |===
  ```
- using CSV content:

  ```
  ,===
  a|b,done
  ,===
  ```

The advantage of the literal block is that it prevents the regex from being interpreted somehow by the backend.